# rails, testing log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to test my controller - SessionsController.
There is action new which creates a session.
Look at https://github.com/matiit/myblog

Test method i wrote:
https://github.com/matiit/myblog/blob/master/test/functional/sessions_controller_test.rb
I can't make it working (now there is only checking for response :success)

It is like that now:

```
test "should log in" do
    post :create, :post => {:email => 'matiit@gmail.com', :password => 'test'}
    assert_response :success
    puts session[:admin_id]
  end
```

And still, session[:admin_id] ain't that what it should be

Answer (score 1):

If you're using RESTful resources, you can't `put` to `:new`. Try `post` to `:create`.